# Delete data based on a column and latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the below Table, i need to get the query for table to Get the Delete query to remove the Unique Employee based on the older date of joining.

The result should have unique EmpNo, where the Doj is latest.
Below is the table data query

```
DECLARE @TableTest TABLE (
    [Sid] [int] NULL,
    [EmpNo] [int] NULL,
    [EmpName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DoJ] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TableTest VALUES 
 (101,'Suresh',20160517)
,(102,'Ravi',20160312)
,(101,'Ramu',20161022)
,(103,'Kumar',20160308)
,(104,'Gopi',20160411)
,(104,'Sridhar',20160620)
,(104,'Suresh',20161012)
```

Expected result

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the rows, you can do:

```
with todelete as (
      select tt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by EmpNo order by Sid desc) as seqnum
      from @tabletest
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum <> 1;
```

Comment: ,My suggesstion is instead  of "delete from todelete where seqnum <> 1" query directly use "SELECT * from todelete
WHERE  seqnum = 1;"

Comment: @Mansoor . . . The question is ambiguous as to whether the OP wants a `select` or `delete`.  I chose `delete` because of "Get the Delete query to remove the Unique Employee based on the older date of joining.".